# Possible to insert values into stream asynchronously in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which downloads the RSS Feed and parses it. After that, I iterate through each team and do some processing on it. For now, this processing is asynchronous and whenever it completes I yield it but that means each item will be processed linearly. Is there a way to process all the items once and yield them as they are processed?

High level code:

```
Stream<String> processRSSFeedItems() async* {
    RSSFeed rssFeed = RSSFeed("some URL");
    for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rssFeed.items.lengthl itemIndex++){
         String processedItem = await processRssItem(rssFeed.items[itemIndex]);
         yield processedItem;
    }
}

void refreshRssFeed(){
    var stream = processRSSFeedItems();
    stream.listen((item) => setState(() => something(item));
}
```

Is there any way to call processRssItem() for all items without waiting for the previous process to complete and yield them as they arrive?

Comment: inside for loop store the values in List and call `yield` after for loop.

Comment: not able to follow but I think you are saying on similar lines as Rahul mentioned below and if that is the case that won't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the elements to a [StreamController](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) as they arrive, and return the stream.

It is considered best practice that [streams should wait for subscribers before starting their work](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#waiting-for-a-subscription). This is achieved by using the `onListen` callback of the `StreamController`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
...

Stream<String> processRSSFeedItems() {
  late StreamController<String> controller;

  void startProcessRssFeedItems() {
    RSSFeed rssFeed = RSSFeed("some URL");
    int workers = rssFeed.items.length;
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rssFeed.items.length; itemIndex++) {
      processRssItem(rssFeed.items[itemIndex]).then(
        (processedItem) {
          controller.add(processedItem);
          if (--workers == 0) {
            controller.close();
          }
        },
        onError: (error) {
          if (--workers == 0) {
            controller.close();
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

  controller = StreamController<String>(
    onListen: startProcessRssFeedItems,
  );

  return controller.stream;
}
```

Comment: I had a cursory read of StreamController and this looks like will solve the problem, I will check it and accept it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: instead of controller.sink.add() I followed this article: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#using-a-streamcontroller. I used controller.add() and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing knowledge, I was unaware of StreamController.

Comment: @TarunChawla calling `.add()` directly is equivalent to `.sink.add()`. I will update my answer to simply call `.add()` directly on the controller.

Comment: You can change it while returning stream as well and also mention the listener has to listen first before adding data to stream otherwise listener won’t get callback. @mmcdon20

Comment: @TarunChawla I have updated the code to more closely align with the advice from the article.

Comment: "the listener has to listen first before adding data to stream otherwise listener won’t get callback" this isn't right however, as the article explains, "When a stream has no subscriber, its StreamController buffers events, which can lead to a memory leak if the stream never gets a subscriber". A listener would receive the buffered data if it subscribed after there was buffered data available, the issue is that you risk doing unnecessary work if you start the processing before you receive listeners, but then end up not having any listeners.

Comment: I understand now what was the issue. You are right, in my code there was one more issue which could have caused this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
List<Future<String>> futures = <Future<String>>[];
for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rssFeed.items.length; itemIndex++){
     futures.add(processRssItem(rssFeed.items[itemIndex]));
}

// Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results.
final result = await Future.wait<String>(futures);

for(var i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++) {
    yield result[i];
}
```

Comment: I think this won't work as result will be returned once all futures are completed. In my case, I would like to update the UI as soon as one item is processed.
Basically, I need a way to update these processed RSS items as soon as they are processed, your solution will enable parallel processing but in the end, I have to wait for all processes which are quicker than the original but still not the solution.

Comment: Check my answer, I used while loop for that

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> "For now, this processing is asynchronous and whenever it completes I
> yield it but that means each item will be processed linearly. Is there
> a way to process all the items once and yield them as they are
> processed?"

"yield" in this context is equivalent to "return". So Stream will not fit your use-case because Streams are designed to be listened for values iteratively, not for "all the items once". For "all the items once" you should use `Future` and `return` the value, not `yield`. Using `while` loop instead of using `for` loop on `List<Future>` will process them one-by-one:

```
    Future getAllWhenProcessed()async{
      var items = rssFeed.items;
      var count = items.length;
      var results = [];
      while(count > 0){
         results.add(await processRssItem(items[--count]));
       }
      return results;
    }
```

Then just

```
getAllWhenProcessed().then((value){ updateUi(); });
```

Comment: But that means items will be processed one after the other, how it is different from the original question? I find the mmcdon20 solution will work better, I am yet to implement it but that looks like a feasible solution.